# Powershell Get-ADUser select return {}instead of values

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I do a `get-aduser` followed by a `select`, some columns returns the value `{}` (or `"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"` when I do an export to CSV file).

The command is the following one:

```
Get-ADUser -properties * | select Surname,LastName,FullName,DisplayName
```

And the values returned:

```
| Surname  | LastName       | Fullname | DisplayName    |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- |
| John     | {}             | {}       | John Doe (User)|
```

Comment: The AD properties should be `Surname` (or LDAP `sn` instead of LastName), `GivenName` (or LDAP `givenName`--> First name), `Name` (or LDAP `cn` instead of FullName). Have a look at [New-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser) to see how the attributes are named

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this @{N='o';E={$_.o[0]}} and by using the correct names for the attributes I was able to extract the informations I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "LastName" with "GivenName" and "Fullname" with just "Name".

I have tried and for me it works this way.

```
Get-ADUser "YourSearch" -properties * | select Surname,GivenName,Name,DisplayName
```

Comment: Thank you !  It works but Then I still have an issue with some values that show up in the powershell console between {value} and on the csv extract "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"

Comment: @Noemie could you provide all of your code? might help finding a solution :)

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter {extensionattribute6 -like "EAD" -OR extensionattribute6 -like "ADM" } -properties * | select O Surname,GivenName,Name,DisplayName,DistinguishedName,Mail,Company,Co,c,countryCode,O,Office,Manager,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,ExtensionAttribute1,ExtensionAttribute4,ExtensionAttribute6,ExtensionAttribute8,ExtensionAttribute12,ExtensionAttribute13 | Export-CSV AllADcomputerslist.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Comment: @Noemie Try adding this. I think [ ] is fixing your Error

Surname,GivenName,Name,DisplayName,DistinguishedName,Mail,Company,Co,c,countryCode,[O],Office,Manager,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,[ExtensionAttribute1],[ExtensionAttribute4],[ExtensionAttribute6],[ExtensionAttribute8],[ExtensionAttribute12],[ExtensionAttribute13]

Comment: I fixed it using this @{N='o';E={$_.o[0]}}. But thank you for the help!